# Magento product getFinalPrice for customer in custom script

Tags: php, magento

I have several Catalog Price Rules for certain customer groups. When viewing the product as the logged-in customer the price displays correctly. I would like to create an inventory file which I can send to the customer which has this discounted pricing. How do I do it?

**What I've tried:**

- Starting a session for the customer (with `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId)`) before getting the product collection, but that didn't seem to affect `$product->getFinalPrice()`.

  > *EDIT:* I should also say that I've confirmed that the session is working correctly by echoing the customer group id from the session.
- Adding the product to a `sales/quote` created for that customer, then getting the price off of the `quote_item` but that didn't work either.
- I followed `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getFinalPrice()` and found two event observers, `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice()` and `processAdminFinalPrice()`. It looks like I should be able to set a customer group id on the product so I've also tried doing that ... no luck. The logic to determine customer group id in `processFrontFinalPrice()` is shown below:

  ```
  if ($observer->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
      $gId = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerGroupId();
  } elseif ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
      $gId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
  } else {
      $gId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the method head? `public function login($username, $password)`. You can't use login() with a customerId.

But there is:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);
```

Comment: Sorry, `loginById` is what I'm using

Comment: Do you get the products as a collection? Dis you add the prices? I have no code here, but there is a method on product collection like `addPriceData()` or something like this.

Comment: Actually no, I load the product with `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)`